# Were the 30 Rock Live episodes shot at 30 Rock?

Tags: film-location, 30-rock

Were the 30 Rock live episodes, one each from seasons 5 and 6 shot from studio 6H at 30 Rock itself or were they shot at a different location? Since there were at least more than 4 different sets in that same one episode, were portions of it shot live and others prerecorded, like how SNL does it for its sketches frequently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

"Live Show", the fourth episode of the fifth season was shot in Studio 8H. From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_Show#Production):

> Studio 8H in the GE Building at 30 Rockefeller Plaza is where Saturday
>   Night Live (SNL) is filmed and was used as the location for "Live
>   Show"

"Live from Studio 6H", the nineteenth episode of the sixth season was also shot in Studio 8H. Again, from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_from_Studio_6H#Production):

> Studio 8H in the GE Building at 30 Rockefeller Plaza is where Saturday
>   Night Live (SNL) is filmed and was used as the location for "Live from
>   Studio 6H".

[image]